# ASP.Net MVC Razor Sum and Count functions

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Is it possible to use "Sum" within Razor, so you can sum up what has been interated through on the view.  ie. my view is like this:

```
@model IEnumerable<cb2.ViewModels.ResultsVM>
...
@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Qualified)
    </td>
  ...
 }
```

I then want to sum up all of the Qualified in at the bottom of the screen similar to this:

```
@Model.Qualified.Sum()
```

But I get the error:

`'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<cb2.ViewModels.ResultsVM>' does not contain a definition for 'Qualified'`

I thought it would have been easy in Qazor to simply use Sum or Count on a model?

thanks, Mark

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I think  you want:

```
@Model.Sum(i => i.Qualified)
```

`Qualified` is a property of the *items* within the model, not the model itself.

Comment: In ASP.NET Core 1.1 `@Model.Sum(...)` is not recognized. What's an alternative?

Comment: It should work fine - ask a new question with your existing code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: I got it working. I am using a property in my ViewModel that is a list of rows, say, `myViewModel.listOfTableRows = (LINQ query).ToList()`. And I'm iterating through that list. So, in that case, I needed to use `@Model.listOfTableRows.Sum(c => c.ColumnName)` and **not** `@Model.Sum(...)`. But yours and `musefan`s solution helped me to a right direction (Thank you).

Answer (score 4):

Remember that `Model` is an `IEnumerable<cb2.ViewModels.ResultsVM>`, it does not contain a property for `Qualified`, but each item within the collection does. So you can call `Sum` directly on the collection and specify the property that you want to sum, namely `Qualified`...

```
@Model.Sum(x => x.Qualified)
```

Comment: I'm using ASP.NET Core 1.1, And VS2015 editor's `Intellisense ` does not recognize `@Model.Sum(...)` How can this be resolved?

Comment: It's working now - as explained in my comments above.